# TapGestureRecognition on multiple uiview in single uiviewcontroller

Tags: iphone, uigesturerecognizer, uitapgesturerecognizer, xcode4.6.3

I am developing application in which subview four `UIVIEW` adding `TapGestureRecognition`. but selector is working for fourth view only. Can anyone tell me where my logic is wrong.

here is code
In `viewdidload` I create four view dynamically.

```
 Where imageframe and contentarea is Uiview:
contentarea addsubview imageframe.
self.view addsubview contentarea

rect =CGRectMake(0,0 , 160, 230);
        view1 = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:rect];
        view1.backgroundColor=[UIColor greenColor];
        view1.tag=viewtag;
        [view1.layer setBorderColor: [[UIColor darkGrayColor] CGColor]];
        [view1.layer setBorderWidth: 0.5];
        [self.imageFrame addSubview:view1];

        rect =CGRectMake(161,0, 159, 230);
        view2 = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:rect];
        view2.tag=viewtag+1;
        view2.backgroundColor=[UIColor blueColor];
        [view2.layer setBorderColor: [[UIColor darkGrayColor] CGColor]];
        [view2.layer setBorderWidth: 0.5];
        [self.imageFrame addSubview:view2];

        rect =CGRectMake(0,231 , 160, 230);
        view3 = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:rect];
        view3.tag=viewtag+2;
        view3.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
        [view3.layer setBorderColor: [[UIColor darkGrayColor] CGColor]];
        [view3.layer setBorderWidth: 0.5];
        [self.contentArea addSubview:view3];

        rect =CGRectMake(161,231 , 169, 230);
        view4 = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:rect];
        view4.tag=viewtag+3;
        view4.backgroundColor=[UIColor redColor];
        [view4.layer setBorderColor: [[UIColor darkGrayColor] CGColor]];
        [view4.layer setBorderWidth: 0.5];
        [self.contentArea addSubview:view4];


     UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(oneTap:)];

        [singleTap setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
        [singleTap setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
        [view1 addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
        [view2 addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];

        [view3 addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];

        [view4 addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
```

Comment: Pls explore ur code. how u add subviews and add gesture both.

Comment: You create a subView say view1 and then add it in the contentArea ... then you create a subview view2 and then add it in contentArea replacing the older view1... got it?

Comment: i didnt replacing both view1 and view 2 will be in content area next to each other

Answer (score 0):

Gesture recognizers can be attached to only one view. Unfortunately, you can't find this in documentation, but you may notice that recognizer class has a view property, which is a pointer to view the gesture is attached to.